# How can I delete specific jobs from Resque queue without clearing the whole queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque

I'm using Resque workers to process job in a queue, I have a large number of jobs > 1M in a queue and have some of the jobs that I need to remove ( added by error). Crating the queue with the jobs was not an easy tasks, so clearing the queue using resque-web and adding the correct jobs again is not an option for me.

Appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  Was it very slow to use destroy?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In resque's sources (Job class) there's such method, guess it's what you need :)

```
# Removes a job from a queue. Expects a string queue name, a
# string class name, and, optionally, args.
#
# Returns the number of jobs destroyed.
#
# If no args are provided, it will remove all jobs of the class
# provided.
#
# That is, for these two jobs:
#
# { 'class' => 'UpdateGraph', 'args' => ['defunkt'] }
# { 'class' => 'UpdateGraph', 'args' => ['mojombo'] }
#
# The following call will remove both:
#
#   Resque::Job.destroy(queue, 'UpdateGraph')
#
# Whereas specifying args will only remove the 2nd job:
#
#   Resque::Job.destroy(queue, 'UpdateGraph', 'mojombo')
#
# This method can be potentially very slow and memory intensive,
# depending on the size of your queue, as it loads all jobs into
# a Ruby array before processing.
def self.destroy(queue, klass, *args)
```

Comment: If you're using ActiveJob, `Resque::Job.destroy` isn't going to be helpful, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589052/activejob-with-resque-enqueuing-jobs-with-uninteded-arguments/40066148#40066148

Answer (score 24):

To remove a specific job from queue you can use the  destroy method. It's very easy to use,
For example if you want to remove a job with class Post and id x, which is in queue named queue1
You can do like this..

```
Resque::Job.destroy(queue1, Post, 'x')
```

If you want to remove all the jobs of particular type from a queue you can use

```
Resque::Job.destroy(QueueName, ClassName)
```

You can find it's documentation at

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/resque/Resque%2FJob.destroy

Answer (score 6):

The above solutions work great if you know all of the arguments passed to the job. If you have a situation where you know *some* of the arguments passed to the job the following script will work:

```
queue_name = 'a_queue'
jobs = Resque.data_store.peek_in_queue(queue_name, 0, 500_000);
deleted_count = 0

jobs.each do |job|
  decoded_job = Resque.decode(job)
  if decoded_job['class'] == 'CoolJob' && decoded_job['args'].include?('a_job_argument')
    Resque.data_store.remove_from_queue(queue_name, job)
    deleted_count += 1
    puts "Deleted!"
  end
end

puts deleted_count
```