# ActiveJob with Resque: enqueuing jobs with uninteded arguments

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, resque, rails-activejob

Trying to implement some kind of cancel job functionality. In order to [destroy a job with Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/v1.25.2/lib/resque/job.rb#L157-L181), one needs the specific arguments passed to it. It appears I'm passing in unintended information by mistake though.

[image]

I'm expecting just the arguments value to be within the outside brackets. I'm creating the job like so:

```
PhysicalServerProvisionJob.perform_later('123')
```

I'd like to be able to:

```
Resque::Job.destroy(:default, PhysicalServerProvisionJob, '123')
```

However this isn't possible due to the extra information passed in. If this is unavoidable, is there another way to destroy a specific queued job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40066148/1321186), I solved the problem this way:

```
Resque.size('default').times do 
  job = Resque.reserve('default')
  next if job.nil? || job.args.first['arguments'].first == id
  Resque.push('default', class: job.payload_class.to_s, args: job.args)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `Resque::Job.destroy` is looking for an exact match of all arguments, it's not going to be helpful for looking up an ActiveJob class.

Here's the script I wrote to solve this:

```
# Pop jobs off the queue until there are no more
while job = Resque.reserve('default')
  # Check this job for the ActiveJob class name we're looking for;
  # if it does not match, push it back onto a different queue
  unless job.args.to_s.include?('PhysicalServerProvisionJob')
    Resque.push('another_queue', class: job.payload_class.to_s, args: job.args)
  end
end
```

Comment: This won't work if I have more than one job of the same class on the same queue.

Comment: @Jerrod I think the approach would still work, you would just need to add additional conditions on `job.args`. In this example I'm only checking `job.args` for the class name, but you could filter based on anything in that hash.